# What command should I use to be warned of this collision beforehand?

Tags: tex-core

After a hunt through several subfiles, I've narrowed down what I thought was a bug down to this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}
$\R$
\newdimen\R
\R=.4cm
$\R$
\end{document}
```

Clearly user error. Although this is what I get for copy and pasting code without paying too close attention to the variables they use. What commands should I use to be warned of this collision in compiling instead of getting the error `! Missing number...` and having to scour several files for what this could be?

I feel like this is along the lines of `\def` versus `\newcommand`.

Comment: Use LaTeX's `\newlength` instead of `\newdimen`.

Comment: by the way, use `\the\R` instead of `\R` if it is a dimen register and you want to typeset its value (in pt units)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use LaTeX's `\newlength` and `\setlength` instead of `\newdimen` and `=` assignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}
$\R$
\newlength\R
\setlength\R{.4cm}
$\R$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's the same as the problem with `\def`.

The `\newdimen` macro comes from plain TeX and it's in LaTeX for historical reasons: in order to ease transition from plain TeX, LaTeX was loaded with a copy of plain TeX, barring a few commands that were reused (`\line`, for instance).

The only difference between plain TeX's and LaTeX's `\newdimen` is that the former is `\outer` and the latter isn't.

```
\outer\def\newdimen{\alloc@1\dimen\dimendef\insc@unt}  %% <-- plain TeX

\def\newdimen{\alloc@1\dimen\dimendef\insc@unt} %% <--- LaTeX (up to 2015)
```

The LaTeX definition has slightly changed in 2015, because a different set of allocation macros was introduced to cope with the extended range of registers afforded by e-TeX.

The `\alloc@` macro in LaTeX was (and its current variant is) essentially the same as in plain; the `\dimendef` primitive (the ultimate responsible for assigning the desired meaning to `\foo` in `\newdimen\foo`) does no check for definedness of the control sequence.

The LaTeX commands that do definitions and allocations and are documented in the manual all do a check.

Users who know about `\newdimen` may exploit it, if they so wish, with the *caveat* that they should know what they're doing. And, much more important, they should not hand a preamble filled with `\newdimen` and `\def` to their mates or colleagues who aren't supposed to be TeX gurus and will be thoroughly confused by weird error messages such as `Missing $` when trying to print *façon• (just because their friend's preamble had `\def\c{\gamma}`, this actually happened).

Is there a difference between `\newdimen` and `\newlength`, apart from the check? Yes, but minor: `\newlength` is a wrapper around plain TeX's `\newskip`, so it allocates a `\skip` register rather than a `\dimen` one. This difference may bite if one doesn't use LaTeX syntax for setting lengths, that is `\setlength`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper around `\newdimen` that gives you an error in that case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\newdimension}[1]{%
  \ifundef{#1}
    {\newdimen#1}
    {\errmessage{command \expandafter\string#1 already defined - can't create dimension}}}

\begin{document}
$\R$
\newdimension{\R}
\R=.4cm
$\R$

\newdimension{\mydim}
\mydim=.4cm
\showthe\mydim
\end{document}
```

Comment: That'll work. If there's not a native command, I'll accept this.

Comment: As far as I know there is none, sorry...

Comment: @AndiW Yes, there is, see my answer.

Comment: Arrgghh... sometimes you don't think about the most basic things... I'll take the blame...